# Integrate twitter in a BlackBerry application

Tags: blackberry, twitter

I want to integrate Twitter in my BlackBerry application.
Is there an api or documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [jibjib library](http://code.google.com/p/jibjib/) - based on J2ME it should work on BlackBerry.

Comment: i have just tried jibjib app into my device first.but it gives an error "java.io.IOException:Tunnel Failed".do you have any idea?

Comment: You're probably on a GSM device - you'll need to either set your APN in the device settings or append it to the URLs used by the library (not sure if the library allows for that).

Answer (score 0):

same problem that libraries gives a "tunnel failed" exception when you are using the BIS network...
I achieve the Blackberry-twitter implementation based on this post

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Twitter-Implementation-in-Blackberry/td-p/548578

Answer (score -1):

Hello follow this: [Integrating twitter in a blackberry application](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Twitter-is-Integrated-in-BlackBerry/m-p/1698157) work flawlessly for me. It provides the basic needed functionalities like tweet, follow, unfollow...

Hope this helps..
Cheers!